# Content overlapping with "position:fixed"

Tags: html, css

When I give the `header` DIV in the code below a `position:fixed` CSS value, the `content` DIV goes up and overlaps it. How can I keep my content DIV below the header?

Here's my code:

```
<div class="header"  style="width:100%; height:50px; positon:fixed;" ></div>    
<div class="content" style="width:100%; height:800px;"></div>           
<div class="footer"  style="width:100%; height:40px;"></div>
```

Comment: `margin-top:50px` should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the div with `position:fixed` property `top:0` and the `.content` div `margin-top:50px` (the height of the fixed `.header` div) :

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/B8UH9/)